# A question regarding certain sequences in hyperfinite type $II_1$ factor

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, oa.operator-algebras, operator-theory, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let us consider the hyperfine type $II_1$ factor $\mathcal M$ arising from the inclusion $M_2\subseteq M_{2^2}\subseteq \dots M_{2^k}\subseteq\dots$ of matrix algebras with the normalised trace $\tau$. Consider $
x_n=\begin{bmatrix} n&0\\0&-n\end{bmatrix}\in M_2$ as elements of $\mathcal M.$   Is it true that there is a constant $>0$. such that for any $\lambda>0$ there is a projection $e\in\mathcal M$ such that $\sup_{n\geq 1}\|_\|_\infty≤\lambda$ and $\tau(1−)≤$?